# Laravel 5.7: User Not Set When Throwing NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-authorization

I am overriding the rendering of a couple of exceptions in the `App\Exceptions\Handler` so I can return custom error pages. However, on some of the exceptions the `auth()->user()` is *not* set.

In the `render`-method, I am just dumping the user like this:

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    dd(auth()->user());

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

When the exceptions are of the type `NotFoundHttpException,` the user isn't set. What would be the best solution for getting the user in these exceptions?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's the solution, but read on for a different recommendation.**

By default, Laravel's authentication runs via the session. The session is explicitly started in the [`web` middleware group](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.7.19/app/Http/Kernel.php#L33).

If a route is not wrapped in the `web` middleware group (as a non-existent / 404 route would be), the middleware doesn't run, and the session isn't started. Therefore Laravel can't know if there is a session user.

**Best solution:** define a [fallback route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#fallback-routes) which was built for exactly this purpose.

**Another solution, with gotchas:** move the `StartSession` middleware into the global group that runs on every request.

/app/Http/Kernel.php:

```php
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    // +++ MOVED SESSION START HERE BELOW +++
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
];
```

#### But, should you...?

First, there's a reason the session doesn't load on every request by default: it creates extra overhead that might not be needed on every request. For example, if your website is configured to always use Laravel as the request handler, *every* 404 will route through Laravel. And there are a lot - crawlers and bots are constantly scouring the web for known insecure web paths. Take a look at your access logs.

Also, if you create self-contained error pages that don't depend on external application logic, you can reuse them at the server level. If Apache or Nginx throws an error, Laravel won't be there at all to dictate the output.

TL;DR: You can enable sessions on 404 and other pages, but understand the trade-offs. Personally, I recommend avoiding application logic on error pages.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I ended up using `Route::fallback()` instead to avoid the unnecessary overhead. [As you can see here](https://twitter.com/themsaid/status/910135205989625856), it seems it was created for this exact reason.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Auth::user()
```

It should work the same way. Make sure you're including the **Auth** library.

Comment: `auth()` is just a helper method that returns the `Auth`-facade. Meaning, it is practically the same thing.